# How do you heal without opening the inventory?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

I've seen some videos where people would heal themselves without using the mouse to click on the healing items, how can you do that?

Something like this:

Comment: I think you can just hit tab and then 1/2/3/4 for the top items in your inventory, which should automatically be healing items to use them so it's a quick tab in and out - otherwise you may have to try and rebind a key to it but I can't find anything that let's you do that

Comment: @n_palum didn't know you could do that but, anyways, that's not exactly what I'm looking for. I've seen people started healing without even opening the inventory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found a [tips and tricks thread guide](https://www.reddit.com/r/PUBATTLEGROUNDS/comments/63z6zc/battlegrounds_tips_and_tricks/) that explains the kind of thing I was thinking of. (A little bit down in the Control Tips section).

By default, **healing items are bound to numbers 7, 8, 9, 0** and are automatically sorted in your inventory from strongest to weakest at the top of your inventory. These *can*  be rebound as well. So from your video, the player is likely hitting one of those keys that corresponds to his healing items.

Answer (score 5):

Use Alphabetic numbers of your keyboard

`7` = Medkit
`8` = First Aid Kit
`9` = Bandage
`0` = Painkillers (then if no left, uses Energy Drink)

Works with QWERTY keyboards, for example AZERTY keyboards will have to remap the keys to properly use these

Comment: Of all of these, "Bandage" is the only proper name of the items.

Comment: @n_palum If you have the correct name feel free to edit I don't have, my game is localised in french

Comment: Ah, didn't know. That's why I generalized as them getting sorted Strongest heal to Weakest.